# "Аккумулятор" — почему пишутся две буквы "к"?

Tags: орфография, заимствования, удвоенные-буквы, буквы

Данное слово произносится с одним звуком [к] — тогда в чём смысл писать две буквы "к"? В других славянских языках, например, пишется одна буква "к". Почему люди сверху не хотят упрощать русский язык? Почему в других написание гораздо проще, чем в русском, и по факту такая русская оригинальность ничем не обоснована (пишешь одно, а говоришь другое): разве что этимологией слова (accumulator, latinium language), но это уже заимствование, а не оригинальность.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147169/discussion-on-question-by--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

> Данное слово произносится с одним звуком [к] — тогда в чём смысл
> писать две буквы "к"?

Из справочника **[«ОРФОГРАФИЧЕСКОЕ КОММЕНТИРОВАНИЕ РУССКОГО СЛОВАРЯ»:](https://oross.ruslang.ru/abc/part?start=2116&end=2416)**

***акк*умуля́тор** (нем. Akkumulator от лат. ac-cumulātor из ac-cumulo «наполняю, собираю в кучу»)…

◊ **Иноязычная непродуктивная приставка *ак*- выделяется в данном слове при сравнении с родственными словами *кумулятивный*, *кумуляция*.**